# How to get selected rows of columns between x and y

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to write a query that returns me the selected rows of the columns based on x and y row values of another column.

But the following query is returning me all the rows of the two selected columns even though I've specified a range. Could anyone please tell me what's wrong I'm doing?

```
select username, password 
from loginuser 
group by username, password 
having count(id) between '1' and '2'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HAVING` operator is to be applied to aggregate functions - if you want to pick those rows where a `SUM` exceeds a certain value or something.

You just want a regular selection - use a `WHERE` clause for that:

```
SELECT username, password 
FROM dbo.loginuser 
WHERE id BETWEEN 1 and 2
```

This will select all rows where the value of `ID` is between 1 and 2.

If you want to select by row number, ordered by ID - you need something like this:

```
;WITH RowNumberValues AS
(
   SELECT username, password,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS 'RowNum' 
   FROM dbo.loginuser 
)
SELECT username, password
FROM RowNumberValues
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 2
```

If you don't have any `SUM` or `COUNT` in your query, you shouldn't be using a `GROUP BY` either...

Is that what you're looking for?? Based on your question and query, it's not entirely clear what you're really looking for.... can you describe in more detail **what** you want to select'?

Comment: Hello, I want to get all values of 'username' and 'password' based on the row number of the id column. Am I clear now?

Comment: @Dusk: almost - so you want all rows with an `ID` **value** between 1 and 2? Is that it? That's what my query would select. Or do you want to **sort the rows** by ID and then select rows no. 1 through 12 or something?? Could you **show us** some of your rows??

Answer (score 1):

#### Why your query doesn't work

```
select username, password 
from loginuser 
group by username, password 
having count(id) between '1' and '2'
```

Note: COUNT() returns an int. SQL Server will convert your *quoted* (next time, please don't) `'1' and '2'` and make them the integer values `1 and 2`.

The query means:

- **FROM**: get data from table loginuser
- **GROUP BY**: for every DISTINCT set of username, password, group them together
- **SELECT**: during the grouping, retrieve the columns `username`, `password` and calculate `count(id)` which is how many rows there are with that SAME username and password
- **HAVING**: using the counts produced, limit the results to only those where the unique combination of username+password appears EXACTLY once or twice in the table

#### What did you want?

The first two distinct username and password combinations, in no particular order?

```
select TOP 2 username, password 
from loginuser 
group by username, password
```

The latest two rows for each distinct username + password combination in the table loginuser? (you need the `PARTITION BY` clause)

```
select username, password 
from
(
  select *, rn=row_number() over (
    partition by username, password order by id desc)
  from loginuser
) X
WHERE rn between 1 and 2
```